# Tensorflow input shape of conv3d

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am having video of (x,y) height and width, I am resizing the video to height 320 and width 120 with 3 channel of RGB.
Now I am merging 60 frames from a video and created depth of 60 from total 10200 frames.
Now I am not sure for training model with conv3d my input shape of (170, 60, 320, 120, 3) is correct.
Is this format correct (batch, depth, height, width, channel) for input_shape in tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Conv3D docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3D) in the latest version of tensorflow as of this post, the default shape is *channels_last*. But you can change the `data_format` parameter to be either `channels_last` or `channels_first`. And it is always `batch_size` first. So in your case, a proper setup could be

```py
input_shape =(170, 60, 320, 120, 3)
Conv3D(n_filters, kernel_size, input_shape=input_shape[1:])
```

OR

```py
input_shape =(170, 3, 60, 320, 120)
Conv3D(n_filters, kernel_size, input_shape=input_shape[1:], data_format='channels_first')
```